# What happens to the original timeline Thanos's ship?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame, avengers-infinity-war

During the events of *Avengers: Infinity War*, Thanos takes Gamora from his ship to Vormir to get the Soul Stone, then heads directly to Titan, and afterwards to Earth to retrieve the Mind Stone. After that we know he "retires" on his farm planet, and then gets killed by Thor at the beginning of *Avengers: Endgame*.

Since Nebula was last on that ship as well prior to heading to Titan, she knew where it was. None of Thanos's other Children survived.

**What happened to his ship? Is it still out there somewhere?**

Comment: Without proper protection from big guys, it was possibly scavenged by the Ravagers.

Answer (score 5):

We don't know, that version of Sanctuary II is never seen again after Nebula leaves and we don't see Thanos go back there. However, we know that Thanos wasn't wearing his armour during the events of *Avengers: Infinity War* after attacking the Statesman, for example, when he completes the Infinity Gauntlet.

[image: Thanos grimaces in pain after completing the gauntlet with the Mind Stone, power lines coarse through his body]

He leaves that armour on the Statesman but at the end of the film and in *Avengers: Endgame* we see his armour hanging up in the Garden.

[image: Thanos' armour hangs on display outside in the Garden]

This is unlikely to be the armour he was wearing at the beginning of *Avengers: Infinity War* as that was most likely destroyed when Thanos used the Power Stone to destroy the Statesman. We could argue it got transported back to Sanctuary II as well. If so it never leaves again. So it's possible before going to the Garden Thanos went back to his ship picked up a few things, including his armour and then left again. As it isn't seen at the Garden though we know he didn't take it with him.

It stands to reason that if Thanos does go back to Sanctuary II before the Garden he told the Chitauri manning it to go on their own way. If not they would've realised Thanos had completed his plan because half of them were likely Snapped and so likely went their own way after that. So, it's unlikely to be floating in space free for the pickings but we don't know exactly what has become of it because there's no information on it after Nebula escapes.

Comment: Given the power of the completed gauntlet, I don't think Thanos would have much trouble getting his armour back, whether it was destroyed on the Statesman or not.

Answer (score 1):

Tony used the Infinity Gauntlet to dust Thanos' army as well as **all of his equipment and ships** at the end of Endgame.

Per the [original screenplay](https://disneystudiosawards.s3.amazonaws.com/avengers-endgame/Avengers_Endgame.pdf).

> COMPLETE WITH SIX INFINITY STONES. POWER SURGES THROUGH
> TONY, EXCRUCIATING, BUT HE STILL LIFTS HIS HAND...
> TONY
>
> And I...am Iron Man.
>
> SNAP!
> WHOOSH. THE TIDAL WAVE EVAPORATES INTO MIST.
> ALL AROUND THE FIELD, SAKAARANS AND OUTRIDERS FOLD IN ON
> THEMSELVES, ATOMS DISINTEGRATING.
> THANOS LOOKS AROUND, WATCHING HIS TROOPS DISAPPEAR. SHIPS
> VANISH FROM THE SKY. CULLS, CHITAURI, ALL BLOW AWAY...
> LEAVING THANOS STANDING ALONE. AFTER A LONG MOMENT, HE SITS
> DOWN ON A ROCK...AND ACCEPTS HIS FATE. He watches as...
> HIS ATOMS DISSOLVE. FINALLY, THANOS DISAPPEARS

It stands to reason that his alternate (time travel duplicate) Sanctuary II would also get dusted along with whatever army he still had offworld.

Comment: I don’t think this is an indication that the Sanctuary II we saw from IW was snapped by Tony.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - The infinity Gauntlet has zapped Thanos' army. His ship(s) are part of his army.

Comment: Sure, the EG Sanctuary II, my point is I doubt the IW S2 counts as well.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - As a time travel duplicate item, there's no reason it wouldn't still be knocking around.

Comment: But the original, which the question is about, isn’t the duplicate.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - They both got zapped. Why wouldn't they?

Comment: I think the point is to prove they both would. The original was no where near Earth on last sighting and was not currently part of Thanos’ army. We also don’t know what Tony’s Snap was, it may not, and most likely wouldn’t, have covered past things/people from Thanos’ army.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - The Infinity Gems are capable of acting across the entire universe. I can't imagine that Tony told it to dust *only his army on Earth and in orbit.*

Comment: I think both possibilities are equally probable. Tony's snap may or may not have included it based on whether it even occurred to him at the time. My guess is that they left it intentionally vague so it could show up in a future movie eg GotG Vol 3.